# C++ nested namespace alias possible?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have the following code I'm refactoring:

```
namespace Foo
{
    namespace Bar { ...classes... }
}
```

Bar is now moving into a new top-level namespace, but I'ld like to keep API compatibility:

```
namespace Pi { ...classes... } // refactored Foo::Bar
namespace Foo { namespace Bar = Pi; } // API compatibility
```

This doesn't work, since it aliases Foo::Bar::Class to Foo::Pi::Class, but not Pi::Class. Is there a way (short of a macro or typedef'ing all Pi classed) to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should do what you need. It means that any lookup in `Foo::Bar` will find names in `::Pi`.

```
namespace Pi {}
namespace Foo { namespace Bar { using namespace Pi; } }
```

Obviously, this won't preserve binary compatibility.

Comment: Doh, that was too obvious! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Oops, you want it the other way round:

```
namespace Foo {
  namespace Bar {
     using namespace Pi;
  }
}
```